# Pure CSS Parallax additional space problem

Tags: css, parallax

## What I want to achieve

I want to add a parallax effect to a single fullscreen section with dynamic content (has not fixed height) and a background.

I would like that on a scroll the background would move slower than the content and that the background would be high enough to cover the whole content.

## What I've tried

To achieve that I have:

- set `perspective: 10px` to `.root`
- set `transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2)` to `.background`
- put `.background` into `.container` and set it's position to absolute so it has the container's height (which is dependent on content's height)

## Problem

The problem is that when I scroll down to the bottom I can see:

- bottom of the `.content`
- a piece of a `.background`
- a black piece of body's black background (appears on Chrome)

[image: problem's screenshot]

When I would scroll down to the bottom I would like that the `.content` would be the end of the screen and that I wouldn't see anything else beneath it.

## Code

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #000; }

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  perspective: 10px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.content {
  display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between;
  height: calc(100vh + 100px);
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}

.background {
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: -1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(cyan, pink);
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>top content</p>
      <p>center content</p>
      <p>bottom content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="background"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Question

How can I achieve it?
I have no idea how can I make it work.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #000; }

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  perspective: 10px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.content {
  display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}

.content p {

  height: 100vh;
 }

.background {
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: -1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(cyan, pink);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>top content</p>
      <p>center content</p>
      <p>bottom content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="background"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I'm looking for.

You removed `transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);` from the `.background` element and it removes the problem but also it removes the parallax and that's the whole point that I want to achieve that parallax effect (background beneath the content moves slower than content)